# Best way to store array persistently in Android without using SQLite

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I have an array in my android application that I would like to store when the application is closed and then later restore when the application is opened again. I know that one usually stores larger amounts of data in android in a SQLite database. But I just have some arrays I'd like to store. Therefore I would like to know what the best method for doing that is.

Best means the following for me:

- good performance
- easy, non-complicated code
- able t store multi-dimensional arrays and arrayLists

The following are the possibilities that I've come up with:

- JSON
- XML
- Metaprogramming where you store the array in a text file as you would initialize it and then read that using metaprogramming. It's not easy, but doable in Java.

Though that of course in not an exhaustive list. What is the best way to store an array in Java according to the criteria above?

I know this is not a typical Q/A quenstion but I think as I have provided clear criteria and examples, it doesn't violate the stackoverflow "question rules"

Comment: Have you considered SharedPreferences?

Comment: Have you considered a raw binary file? Either standard Serialization or custom?

Comment: Describe in detail these 'some arrays', i.e. primitives or objects as well as the expected array size as any answer or direction would be dependent on what you want to store and how you would like to retrieve it (linear vs random access).

Comment: In my specific case it would be arrays of enums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 [basic methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to data storage in Android.

1. [Internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)- This is basically a private folder where you can write files to. You can write a small file there, and read it back.
2. [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)- Same as internal, except other applications can see it. Usually this is an SD card. This is useful for large data sets that you don't want in internal limited memory, and you don't mind sharing (MP3's, images, etc)
3. [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)- Best for large sets of data in a tabular type format.
4. [Shared Preferences-](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) Best for small amounts of data, use to store preference values, maybe high scores, etc. Doesn't natively store arrays, but you could store a json string, as you mentioned as a possibility.

For storing a set of high scores, I used the Internal storage folder, which seemed to work well enough for my purposes. Once you choose your method, you should be able to figure out how to write/get your data appropriately. If you can't, feel free to ask another question to help figure that piece out.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects in the array are *Serializable*, you can write them to a file that is stored on the sdcard.  This way you won't need to use the database.  Something like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream dataOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
dataOutputStream.writeObject(myList);
```

Then to retrieve the array:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
List<MyObject> myList = (List<MyObject>) inputStream.readObject();
```